# Is there a way to more easily rearrange table seating besides using the Tavern?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

I'd like to rearrange how my players sit at the table, but clicking, dragging, and other attempts don't give me an option to change seating. The only way I know currently is to go to a Tavern, remove all from the table, then add back in the order I want. Is there an easier or more intuitive way to arrange the seating?